# How to pass a variable from one function to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set the value of a variable with one function, and pass it to another so that I can use it to determine the result. Consider the attempt to define the variable 'highlight' below:

Defining functions:

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.more', function(t) {
var highlight = 1;
});

$(document).on('click', '.less', function() {
var highlight = 0;
});
</script>
```

Now I should either have highlight set to 1 or 0. I want to use this in another script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var usericon_info = function(highlight){

    var html = '';
    if(highlight == 0)
        //code... ;

    if(highlight == 1)
        //code... ;

    return html;
    }

});
</script>
```

However, the values don't appear to be passing, where am I going wrong? There is no error in the console.

Comment: You're setting the vars within your function, so they will only be available at that level or deeper. This is an example of `scoping`. If you want those vars available outside your function, initiate them outside your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues - mainly involving `highlight` being defined multiple times in different scopes. These scopes are:

- The `.more` click handler;
- The `.less` clock handler; and
- The anonymous function assigned to the `usericon_info` variable within the scope of the anonymous function passed to `$(document).ready()`.

The `var` keyword is used to defines a variable in the scope of the containing function (or if there is no containing function then the global scope) so you need to define the `highlight` variable once using `var` in a scope common to all the places where it is used - if you do that then all those functions will refer to the same variable.

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var highlight = 0;

    $( '.more' ).on('click', function(){ highlight = 1; });
    $( '.less' ).on('click', function(){ highlight = 0; });

    var usericon_info = function(){
        var html = '';
        if(highlight == 0)
        {
            //code... ;
        }
        else if(highlight == 1)
        {
            //code... ;
        }
        return html;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting the values inside your function, you scope them to that function only. What you're doing here is defining a variable when you click on the class `.more`, and it will be accessible only in that click event, or unless passed as a parameter.

Try this

```
var highlight;
$(document).on('click', '.more', function(t) {
    highlight = 1;
});

$(document).on('click', '.less', function() {
    highlight = 0;
});
```

Remember to take out the var otherwise you just reset the variable value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the variables like globals.

You can do it for 2 diferent ways

1 - You have to declare the variable out of any function like that

```
    var highlight;
$(document).on('click', '.more', function(t) {
    highlight = 1;
});

$(document).on('click', '.less', function() {
    highlight = 0;
});
```

2- You declare the variable witouth the 'var' this way javascript understand is a global.

```
$(document).on('click', '.more', function(t) {
    highlight = 1;
});

$(document).on('click', '.less', function() {
    highlight = 0;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
$(document).on('click', '.more', function(t) {
var highlight = 1;
});

$(document).on('click', '.less', function() {
var highlight = 0;
});
```

to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.more').click(function(t) {
        var highlight = 1;
    });
    $('.less').click(function() {
        var highlight = 0;
    });
});
```

This is better structured to make sure the DOM is ready to be manipulated, and to make
sure your functions fire on the right events.

*Edit:*
I would also look into the jquery .toggle() function. It might be of some use to you.
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: You are still redefining the `highlight` variable in the local scope of each of click handlers and this will hide any instance of `highlight` in a global/parent scope.

Comment: True. I was mostly addressing the syntax errors. Not so much the logic. Haha.